# Disable default browser behavior to move curser right or left when pressing arrow keys in input field

Tags: javascript, mozilla

I am using Firefox to do this but it works in IE6 ... go figure.

Basically I have code written to traverse a grid of input elements using arrow keys. All of that is working just fine. I can move freely to any field using the arrow keys. When I use up or down arrows the select function seems to work correctly by selecting all text in the next field. (desired result)

document.getElementById(id).select();

However when I traverse left or right the text seems to be using a default browser function to move the cursor once to the left or right after the select happens forcing the user to select all the text again (undesired result).

Is there a way to disable that in firefox so my text gets selected correctly? The typical workflow for my users is to just hit the arrow key then start typing numbers ...then repeat.

Comment: Given the easy availability of alternate browsers and modern versions of IE, it's baffling that there are still people on the planet running IE6.

Comment: It's the govt orgs that are stuck with it. They represent a large amount of browsers out there. They keep promising we are going to a more modern version but it never seems to happen :*(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say this behavior is caused by the keyup event. Did you try to stop it?

**edit:** yep, works fine when keyup event is cancelled : http://jsfiddle.net/D6ANY/1/

Answer (score -1):

From your description, it seems to me that you are trying to achieve a "spreadsheet" like effect. If thats the case, then the behaviour you are implementing **could confuse users**. e.g. in spread sheets the selection moves with arrow keys for each cell **but if you have to edit a cell, you need to hit the enter key**. That makes it editable and then hitting the enter key again will make it read-only

Comment: The question was if you could disable the default functionality. Not whats the best way to go about it. My users won't settle for having to hit the enter key. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: I wanted to add this as a comment, but for some strange reason, the "add comment" link wasn't there earlier when I wrote my answer! Maybe I didn't have enough rights?